# A couple of questions regarding the free energy functional in Cahn-Hilliard equation

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

I have two questions regarding the free energy functional choosen for the cahn-hilliard equation.

1. In their paper, https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1744102, they say the gradient part is $(\nabla c)^2$ (Eq. 2.6). However, in many sites I see this term is $|\nabla c|^2$. For the free energy density, boths terms are essentially the same, but not for the derivatives, like the chemical potential, isn't it? where is the secret behind this? Is it hidden in the prefactor term of the derivative?  (Eq. 2.7) (because I don't really understand the one from their paper...). Any clue on this?

ok, I understood this one. It was really silly.

$$(\nabla c)^2=(\nabla c) \cdot (\nabla c) = \left(\frac{dc}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dc}{dy}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dc}{dz}\right)^2=|\nabla c|^2$$

how ever, why do they prefer to express it in terms of the modulus? or to avoid dot product?

2. How is here related the Landau free energy class to the thermodynamical Gibbs free energy? It is just a matter of why they derive it with respect the order parameter to obtain the chemical potential as if it were the Gibbs free energy...